# Binding Tesseract as a static Lib in Xamarin

Tags: ios, binding, xamarin, tesseract

I am trying to add tesseract to my iOS-App. Im doing the App with Xamarin.iOS.
I tried creating a .dll with btouch and used for that the ported version of tesseract on github(https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS). I created the bindings of tesseractOCR.h with Objective-Sharpie and created a 
.dll with the TesseractOCR.a file. 
Everything worked fine but when trying to build my app with the .dll referenced it gives me the attached Errors.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w9cvzozgw4gffdx/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-31%20at%2012.46.24.png

How can I fix them?

Thanks in advance
Alex

Answer (score 3):

This seems a good question and I came here looking for Xamarin bindings for Tesseract library, but there was none on this page. After searching, I found that there are a couple of bindings already for Xamarin:

Classic 
1. https://github.com/sraiteri/Xamarin-Tesseract-OCR-iOS

Unified
2. https://github.com/jherby2k/Xamarin-Tesseract-OCR-iOS-Unified

Xamarin Forms
3. https://github.com/halkar/Tesseract.Xamarin

Also, there seems to be an active and modern porting to swift, and can be found here:
https://github.com/WhitneyLand/SwiftOpenCV

This discussion on Xamarin forum seems also very useful for anybody interested in this question:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3673/help-adding-tesseract-as-a-ios-binding-project

Disclaimer: I have not tried any of them yet, just finished my research, now gonna start my experimentation :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because Tesseract uses c++ and the binding needs to know this.

I would suggest creating a binding project as per [the tutorial at Xamarin](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_objc_libs/). Then [this Xamarin forum post](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6194/problem-linking-in-standard-c-library-when-creating-binding) gives great information on how to add c++ to the LinkWith attribute.